# Show that the standard bounded metric $\min(1,d)$ is topologically equivalent to $d$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(E,d)$ be a metric space.
I already showed that $\delta=\min(1,d)$ is a metric on $E$.
I can't finish the proof that shows that these distances are equivalent.

### What I tried

For $r>0$ and $x\in E$,

- since $\delta\leq d$, $\forall y\in E$, $d(x,y)\leq r\implies \delta(x,y)\leq r$ and $\mathcal B_d(x,r)\subset\mathcal B_\delta(x,r)$,
- let's find $r'>0$ such that $\mathcal B_\delta(x,r')\subset\mathcal B_d(x,r)$…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: What happens if you let $r'=\min\left\{\frac12,r\right\}$?

Comment: I just checked it worked and thank you for that but maybe could you explain what's the intuition behind it? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Gulliver: Sure: the key point here is that $d$ and $\delta$ are identical for distances that are less than $1$, so you just have to make sure that you’re talking about such a distance. I could have used any $\alpha\in(0,1)$ instead of $\frac12$.

Comment: I see but I am not sure to understand why $\min(1,r)$ wouldn't have done it

Comment: @Gulliver: It would (and I see that I inadvertently wrote the wrong right bracket in my previous comment); I thought that choosing something less than $1$ might make the underlying idea a little more apparent without my actually spelling it out right away.

Comment: Oh okay I understand now, thank you!

Comment: @Gulliver: You’re welcome!